# Unable to install the disgenet2r package

Tags: r, installation

```
library(devtools)
install_bitbucket("ibi_group/disgenet2r")

Unable to install dependencies such as SPARQL
ERROR: dependency ‘SPARQL’ is not available for package ‘disgenet2r’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/disgenet2r’
Warning messages:
1: package ‘SPARQL’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages 
2: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/43/7hr3j7q17tn0ns1g67l5vbq80000gn/T//Rtmptk5KoF/file2d1b24460f94/disgenet2r_0.99.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Installing of library(disgenet2r) for further OMIM research

Comment: You've got a version conflict there, like it mentions. You can change your R version or (much more likely what you want) the package version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so, the version of *something* needs to change. I will assume your R version will remain fixed.

I don't know what version of SPARQL you're on, but this is the latest:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SPARQL/SPARQL_1.16.1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Try it again after that. If it's still not working then try:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_version("disgenet2r", version = "0.99.1")
```

Comment: The above code helped install SPARQL, thank you for the help. Another way to install disgenet2r would be as shown here on https://www.disgenet.org/static/disgenet2r/disgenet2r.html#performing-a-disease-enrichment